# Is there a way for a child controller to inherit a service "like" instance from its parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

In my app I have window instances. The app can contain multiple windows and windows can contain multiple views. The views are children of each window instance.

```
function windowController($scope, WindowService) {
    WindowService.setWindowConfig($scope.window);
}

function viewController($scope, WindowService) {
    WindowService.updateDirtyState(true);
}
```

I want to be able to update the window from the view(s). But I only want the children to be able to update their parent window. Being that services are singletons, the view would update all windows.

Is there a way to achieve this without passing some sort of ID around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services *are* singletons, but they can contain constructors for objects other than the one they return.

Here is a skeleton example of a service which takes advantage of this fact:

```
.factory('WindowService', function(){
  var service = {};

  var Window = function() {
    ...
  };

  Window.prototype.doSomething = function(){
    ...
  };

  var View = function(window) {
    this.window = window;
  };

  service.newWindow = function(){
    return new Window();
  }

  service.newView = function(){
    return new View(window);
  }

  return service;
});
```

Assuming every `ViewController` has its own `WindowController` parent, they could be instantiated this way:

```
.controller('WindowController', function($scope, WindowService){
  $scope.window = WindowService.newWindow();
})
.controller('ViewController', function($scope, WindowService){
  $scope.view = WindowService.newView($scope.window);
})
```

There is no reason to worry about id's since the view objects will contain references to their window parents. In fact, if all `ViewController`s have a `WindowController` parent, you could reference that scope variable through prototypical inheritance, via `$scope.window` from the view, bypassing `WindowService` for window object access.

```
.controller('ViewController', function($scope, WindowService){
    $scope.view = WindowService.newView($scope.window);
    // don't need to do $scope.view.window.doSomething(), but you could
    $scope.window.doSomething();
})
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1R97SfucPXi6PUAf0gZo?p=preview)

Comment: The question I asked was too simple, but you did answer the question and answer gave me some new insight on how I could use services in the future. Here's the link to the new question if you want to take a shot at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002095/is-there-a-loosly-coupled-way-to-update-a-parent-directive-from-a-dynamically-cr

Comment: Services are the best way to provide loosely coupled relationships between Angular components, including directives and controllers. Can you provide more specific information, either here or in your new question , about how these components are meant to interact? As of now, I don't see a major difference in how the question is presented.

Comment: If you check out the view directive in the plunker you will see that the views and their controllers are being created dynamically by the view creator directive. This directive is isolated and does not pass on it parent scope. Access to "window" at this point is not possible so I couldn't say $scope.view = WindowService.newView($scope.window);. I'm not sure that I would want to either, wouldn't that cause a coupling to the parent scope? I'd rather pass in the window object at the parent level and be able to modify it from the view.