# Is there a loosly coupled way to update a parent directive from a dynamically created view/controller that is a child of the parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

In my app I have window instances. The app can contain multiple windows and windows can contain multiple views. The views are children of each window instance. The windows and view creator are directive with an isolated scope. I want the views to be loosely coupled to their parent window and not have to something like $scope.$parent

```
module.directive('window', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'windowTemplate.html',
        controller: 'windowController',
        scope: {
            config: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
});

module.directive('view', function($compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
            attrs.$observe('templateUrl', function (url) {
                $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                    var tpl = $compile(response.data)(scope);
                    element.append(tpl);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I initially thought that I could achieve this with a service, but being that services are singletons, the view would update all windows.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Example [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VomDf7aLIkHx0M0cwPtC?p=preview)

Comment: You could give each parent/child "window" element a reference (unique id). Then use `$scope.$broadcast` to communicate back and forth by passing the unique ID.

Comment: I was hoping on not having to pass an ID around and just be able to update the window object more directly via a "service" like utility that was not a singleton. Basically a service that could isolate itself in the context of the window it resides. It may not exist, but I was hoping...

Comment: As far as I know you can't isolate the service to certain scopes, so the ID would be the next-best thing IMO

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data/functions between locations in angular I would suggest reading up on services: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

They allow you to have different parts of your app communicate with one another.

Comment: Services are singletons. If I updated one window from a given view, all windows would be updated. Let me know if I'm missing something. Each window should have its own context. The view(s) should only update their direct parent.

Comment: You can share services across views. They are singletons to your entire angularjs application.

Comment: Right, that's my point. Singletons will not work in this case. I do not want all windows to be updated. I want only update the window where it's child view or views has changed in some way.

Answer (score 0):

As I attempted to demonstrate in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964571/is-there-a-way-for-a-child-controller-to-inherit-a-service-like-instance-from/23964845#comment36991912_23964845), despite the fact that services are singletons, there are easy ways to utilize them for managing multiple, unique object instances.

I think that the real problem you're wrestling with is how to relate a "window" and a "view". It sounds like you have an aversion to utilizing prototypical inheritance for fear of too tightly coupling the elements. Still, one way or another, you're going to have to have some coupling between view and window. Otherwise, they are just independent objects with no relationship to one another.

I suggest that you consider creating a service which is, in part, a factory of window and view objects (ie. similar to my answer to your previous question). Then, since you are using directives with isolate scope, you can share *just the window* scope object with child views, like so (in your window directive template):

```
<view template-url="{{view.templateUrl}}" window="window" ng-show="view.active"></view>
```

If you make the corresponding `scope: {...}` change to all child view directives, they will have access *only to* the parent's scope variable for window. And honestly, in that case, you might even skip making the service, since the window and view directive's could themselves sufficiently encapsulate. Whether or not you need the service will probably depend on other factors outside of the scope of what you've presented for discussion.

If you see an issue with sharing only that scope variable, can you update your question with more information on what your objections are?

Comment: I'm not adverse to this approach, I'm just looking for the "best practices" way of implementing this. This is the part that is confusing to me. It's seems to be commonly stated that services are best practices approach to communication across controllers. But if the window object is already at the view level, why wouldn't I just access it directly in the view ($scope.window.title = 'something'). How is passing window into a service at the view level any less coupled?

Comment: If these elements will always have a parent/child relationship, then the difference in functionality may be nil. Still, my understanding (please someone correct me if I'm off base) is that services are a natural place for state and business logic *because they are singletons*. So now it sounds like we're talking in circles here... but consider that since a service is instantiated only once, it only takes one place in memory. The same is not necessarily true for the properties and logic you put inside of directives or controllers.